# Pandas: Query DF based on number of instances taken place with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df containing AirBnB data. There is one question I am stuck trying to answer. The column of interest, `host_listings_count` contains data of the number of listings each host has.

This is my first attempt querying using Pandas. I would like to know:

**The number of hosts that offer 2 or more properties.**
**my attempt**
`df['host_listings_count'].value_counts().loc[lambda x:x>1]`

```
1.0      12528
2.0       2285
0.0       1767
3.0        609
4.0        236
5.0        137
8.0         87
97.0        84
7.0         81
85.0        81
```

Now, i know this doesnt work. The lambda function's intended purpose is to exlude the first row, leaving me with the rest of the data, to which i then need to total which i assume `.sum()` will suffice. I know the Lda part is filtering the wrong column, so my question is how do I answer my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is first calculate all the unique values over your `host_listings_count` column and exclude the ones you don't want. In your case that's only filtering for more than 1 property. You can then sort this list and use it as index on your value_counts output like so:

```
sorted_values = sorted([x for x in df['host_listings_count'].unique() if x > 1])
df['host_listings_count'].value_counts().loc[sorted_values]
```

Comment: I see, seems clear to follow along with. I wondered if there is a particular method which i could just include a few parameters to, to get my desired result. Your suggestion works, Thank you.  What could i use to find the total of number properties?

Comment: If you were just interested in the total amount of properties from all owners who have 2 or more listed properties you could do that without the value_counts() method by doing: `df.loc[df['host_listings_count']>1].sum()`

Comment: fantastic, thank you for your time and input. I'll be sure to write these down to learn from them. Thanks again

Comment: Happy to help! Also just as additional explanation for the code above. Using the `df['host_listings_count']>1` within the `.loc[]` method basically just subsets your dataset. The return of this all the rows of people that have more than 1 listing. You then actually have to select the column you're interested in and sum over that. So the code above is a bit faulty, as it should be: `df.loc[df['host_listings_count']>1, 'host_listings_count'].sum()`

Comment: with your original input, within the answer given. Can a method be attached to this to obtain the total? I have just realised that I am getting the wrong answer. With the original solution, I can estimate there to be almost 4000 hosts (which sounds right). But with the alternative, im getting a number that doesnt quite make sense. 37,000 to be exact

Comment: I thought you were looking for the number of listings that were from hosts who listed more than one property. If you want to know the number of hosts you can just use the `.shape` property of the df after subsetting or the `.count()` method: `df.loc[df['host_listings_count']>1, 'host_listings_count'].shape[0]` or `df.loc[df['host_listings_count']>1, 'host_listings_count'].count()`.

Comment: thanks bud, managed to suss it out in the end. Lots of things that I've learn thanks to your input and im appreciative of that.